# Jitsi won't start under ubuntu

Tags: sip

I installed jitsi, both from the official repos and a direct download from the webpage. When I try to run it I get the error message:

```
 SIP Communicator is already running and will handle your parameters (if any)

 Launch with the --multiple param to override this behaviour.
```

If I do launch it with --multiple java gives a huge error message and it crashes.

Comment: What is the huge error message?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B6YMVn6A

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't start or launch Jitsi after proper installation, either!
Then after removing Java 8 by following this
http://www.2daygeek.com/uninstall-oracle-java-openjdk-linux/

Then check for current Java version:
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

Jitsi starts as normal now!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this message is displayed when jitsi is already running, which you can test with something like `ps -ef | grep jitsi`. There is also a lock file: `~/.jitsi/.lock`.

I had this problem when trying to run jitsi with java 8. Apparently jitsi does not run with java 8:
[[jitsi-dev] Jitsi doesn't working in Java 8](http://lists.jitsi.org/pipermail/dev/2014-May/thread.html#20925)

Using java 7 fixes it.